# search within time ranges

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to come up with a way to query within a list of time ranges, to assign jobs to different people according to their availability.

So I'm imaging a table stored in MYSQL:

```
Person       | Available (day) | Available (hours) | Free (from) | Free (until)
Mateluna     | Monday          | 10:00 - 13:00     | 10:00       | 13:00
Mateluna     | Monday          | 15:00 - 19:00     | 15:00       | 19:00
DelloStritto | Tuesday         | 12:00 - 18:00     | 12:00       | 18:00
DeFranco     | Monday          | 10:00 - 11:30     | 10:00       | 11:30
Richardson   | Monday          | 08:00 - 10:30     | 08:00       | 10:30
```

*** Where Free (from) and Free (until) would be generated from the Available (hours)**

The idea is that I could create a form that would query the table with parameters like "Monday" & "10:00 - 11:30" and the function would return DeFranco and Mateluna. From what I can think of, it would involve having to do a search within "Available (day)" and to be able to search within the "Available (hours)" time ranges - which I do not know how to do or sure if is possible.

At the moment I could create something that works, but it comes out to be more generic, eg. I can search for "Monday" and see all people available on Mondays and then I'd have to look through the output list to find the people who fit my needs, eg.

```
Mateluna @ 10:00 - 13:00
DeFranco @ 10:00 - 11:30
Richardson @ 08:00 - 10:30
```

Any help, **much** appreciated on how I could approach this problem, I have a feeling it might involve having to store the information differently, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This should by more easy if you avoid multivalued columns and parameters: "10:00 - 11:30" is multivalued because contains 2 values from_time and to_time. Sure you want to continue question in this way?

Answer (score 0):

I think for your purpose you can use the 'AND' or 'joins' in the query.... for example

select * from db_name where available(day) =%s AND available hours between %s and %s;